# CLOCKS_PER_SEC equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I've this code snippet in C++ and have a hard time converting it to C#

```
clock_t now = clock();
myStartTime = start;
myTimeLimit = 5 // in seconds

for (int depth = 2; ((double)(now - myStartTime)) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC < myTimeLimit; depth += 2)
{
    //
}
```

Is this how I should do it?

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
myStartTime = start;
myTimeLimit = 5;

for (int depth = 2; (now - myStartTime).TotalSeconds < myTimeLimit; depth += 2)
{

}
```

Comment: Yes that's how you do it.

Comment: That C++ code snippet you found should be thrown away. Using `clock` for timers like that is really not something anyone would recommend. In both C and C++ there are many much better alternatives, especially in C++ where there are *portable* alternatives (the `clock` function, while in the C and C++ standards, doesn't behave the same on different platforms).

Comment: @Evk - No, `now` and `myStartTime` are both unchanging, that loop will never end.

Comment: @HenkHolterman loop will break inside when a condition meets and this whole code is inside a recursive method.

Comment: Maybe, but it will never break on myTimeLimit.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I just meant that C# code seems to be equivalent of C++ code. Whether any of that works as expected seems to be not the question.

Comment: _"is inside a recursive method"_ - ouch. Do throw this away.

Comment: @HenkHolterman haha.. [here](http://www.pauldix.net/2006/06/code_for_nine_m.html) is the source code, someone should mention that guy. But I've not found a better solution really.

Comment: I get the context now but still, you're missing a pointer or a scope in the original C++ , what you posted here is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx) as a better alternative to achieve this. For example

```
var clt = new CancellationTokenSource(5000);
Task.Run(() => DoSomething(clt.Token));

private static void DoSomething(CancellationToken cltToken)
{
    for (int depth = 2; !cltToken.IsCancellationRequested; depth += 2)
    {
        // . . .
    }

    if (cltToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
        // Time limit reached before finding best move at this depth
    }
}
```